# Webpack Error : GET https://localhost:8080/assets/status 404 (Not Found)

Tags: webpack

I try to create a visual custom on power BI and when I start to run my app I have:
**`GET https://localhost:8080/assets/status 404 (Not Found)`** when i try to run the program, so i'm pretty sure the probleme come from the webpack because if I don't use it I don't have the probleme (but I must use webpack)

And I have this `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path')
const fs = require("fs");

// werbpack plugin
var webpack = require('webpack')
console.log(require.resolve('powerbi-visuals-webpack-plugin'));
const PowerBICustomVisualsWebpackPlugin = require('powerbi-visuals-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
// const Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');
const ExtraWatchWebpackPlugin = require('extra-watch-webpack-plugin');
 
// api configuration
const powerbiApi = require("powerbi-visuals-api");
 
// visual configuration json path
const pbivizPath = "./pbiviz.json";
const pbivizFile = require(path.join(__dirname, pbivizPath));
 
// the visual capabilities content
const capabilitiesPath = "./capabilities.json";
const capabilitiesFile = require(path.join(__dirname, capabilitiesPath));
 
const pluginLocation = './.tmp/precompile/visualPlugin.ts'; // path to visual plugin file, the file generates by the plugin
 
// string resources
const resourcesFolder = path.join(".", "stringResources");
const localizationFolders = fs.readdirSync(resourcesFolder);
 
// babel options to support IE11
let babelOptions = {
    "presets": [
        [
            require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),
            {
                "targets": {
                    "ie": "11",
                },
                useBuiltIns: "entry",
                modules: false
            }
        ]
    ],
    sourceType: "unambiguous", // tell to babel that the project can contains different module types, not only es2015 modules
    cacheDirectory: path.join(".tmp", "babelCache") // path for chace files
};

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/visual.ts',
    // output: {
    //     path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    //     filename: 'visual.bundle.js',
    // },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/.tmp","drop"),
        publicPath: 'assets',
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    },
    mode: "development",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' },
            {
                test: /\.js$/, use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        ignore: ['./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js']
                    }
                }
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
            { test: /\.less$/, use: [
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                },
                {
                    loader: 'less-loader',
                },
            ] }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        // disableHostCheck: true,
        allowedHosts: 'all',
        static: path.join(__dirname, "/.tmp", "drop"), // path with assets for dev server, they are generated by webpack plugin
        compress: true,
        port: 8080, // dev server port
        hot: false,
        // inline: false,
        // cert files for dev server
        https: {
            pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules\\powerbi-visuals-tools\\certs\\PowerBICustomVisualTest_public.pfx')), // for windows
            passphrase: "6529273902027273"
        },
        headers: {
            "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
            "cache-control": "public, max-age=0"
        },
        client: {
            overlay: true,
            progress: true,
        },
    },
    externals: {
        "powerbi-visuals-api": 'null',
        "fakeDefine": 'false',
        "corePowerbiObject": "Function('return this.powerbi')()",
        "realWindow": "Function('return this')()"
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "visual.css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
        // new Visualizer({
        //     filename: "webpack.statistics.dev.html"
        // }),
        // visual plugin regenerates with the visual source, but it does not require relaunching dev server
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({paths:[
            path.join(__dirname, pluginLocation),
            "./.tmp/**/*.*"
        ]}),
        // custom visuals plugin instance with options
        new PowerBICustomVisualsWebpackPlugin({
            ...pbivizFile,
            capabilities: capabilitiesFile,
            stringResources: localizationFolders.map(localization => path.join(
                resourcesFolder,
                localization,
                "resources.resjson"
            )),
            apiVersion: powerbiApi.version,
            capabilitiesSchema: powerbiApi.schemas.capabilities,
            pbivizSchema: powerbiApi.schemas.pbiviz,
            stringResourcesSchema: powerbiApi.schemas.stringResources,
            dependenciesSchema: powerbiApi.schemas.dependencies,
            devMode: false,
            generatePbiviz: true,
            generateResources: true,
            modules: true,
            visualSourceLocation: './src/visual', // "../../src/visual",
            pluginLocation: pluginLocation,
            packageOutPath: path.join(__dirname, "dist")
        }),
        new ExtraWatchWebpackPlugin({
            files: [
                pbivizPath,
                capabilitiesPath
            ]
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            window: 'realWindow',
            define: 'fakeDefine',
            powerbi: 'corePowerbiObject'
        }),
    ]
};
```

I think the probleme come from the place where all the asset and data are beacause if I change the line :`

`publicPath: 'assets',`

in:

`publicPath: '/assets/',`

I have the error : **`GET https://localhost:8080/assets/visual.js 404 (Not Found)`**

I hope somone can help me thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the line:
`path: path.join(__dirname, "/.tmp","drop"),`

in

`path: path.join(__dirname, "/.tmp","drop","assets)`

and now I don't have error (my project don't works but I don't have error)